# create RxCommand with two combined streams

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

I have a form with two inputs: **name** & **address** and a **save** button.

So i've created a **change** and **isValid** commands for each

```
final _nameChangedCommand = RxCommand.createSync<String, String>((x) => x);
final _isNameValidCommand = RxCommand.createSync<String, bool>((x) => x != "");

final _addressChangedCommand = RxCommand.createSync<String, String>((x) => x);
final _isAddressValidCommand = RxCommand.createSync<String, bool>((x) => x != "");
```

I'm trying to create same for save button, where `canSave = _isNameValidCommand && _isAddressValidCommand`, but cant figure out the syntax.

I've created a ZipStream :

```
final _isNameAddressValidStream =
    new StreamZip([_isNameValidCommand, _isAddressValidCommand])
        .map((results) => results.first && results.last)
        .distinct();

final _canSaveCommand =
    RxCommand.createFromStream((_) => _isNameAddressValidStream);
```

but stream is never called.

Any hints?

Comment: Usually people will point you to [combineLatestN](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/combineLatest2.html). I actually work around the issue manually because it didn't work for me, but that was a while back and I might have been using it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes 'combineLatest' came also to my mind. what is important with combineLatest is that it won't issue any data unless it received something on all input Streams. Best to reach that if you add a `.startWith` with an initial value before feeding it to the conbineLatest. Something like

```
final _isNameAddressValidStream =
    Observable.combineLatest2<String, String, bool>(
        _nameChangedCommand.startWith(''),
        _addressChangedCommand.startWidth(''),
        (name, address) => name != '' && address != '');

final _saveCommand = RxCommand.createSyncNoResult(
    (dataObject) => _saveToWhatever, // your actual save function 
    canExecute: _isNameAddressValidStream);
        .distinct();
```

So you only need two commands you can use `_saveCommand` for you Button's `onTap`handler and use the `_saveCommand.canExecute` Observable to feed a `StreamBuilder` that created your button in activate or deactivated state.

Comment: well, i've kinda simplified the code for question. I also need to indicate which field is invalid, but i guess i can simply modify your code to :
`final _isNameAddressValidStream = Observable.combineLatest2<bool, bool, bool>(_isNameValidCommand.startWith(false), _isAddressValidCommand.startWidth(false), (a, b) => a && b);`

right?

P.S. Thanks for RxCommand library :)

Comment: Yep you can or just listen to the two commands and react if they are not valid